# Как сделать так, чтобы буквы не перегораживали нижнее подчёркивание у ссылки?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень бесит что буквы "ф" и "ц" перегораживают нижнее подчёркивание. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Comment: А это подчёркивание как сделано?

Comment: Подчёркивание делал через тег a

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink

Comment: а подчёркивание немного ниже нельзя сделать?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset

Answer (score 2):

помогло text-decoration-skip-ink: none;

Comment: Это абсолютно верный ответ. Помечайте решением.

Answer (score 0):

Можно например сделать `text-underline-position: under;` (Линия расположена под текстовым контентом элемента)

```css
a {
  text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <h1>
     <a href="#">
      My link</a>
   </h1>
</body>
```

Все варианты можно посмотруть **[здесь](https://ru.w3docs.com/uchebnik-css/css-svoistvo-text-underline-position.html)**

---

Можно использовать offset (смещение) у стиля text-decoration

```css
a {
 text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
  text-underline-offset: 0.75em;
  /*text-underline-position: under;*/
}

a.test {
 text-underline-offset: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<h1><a>Специальное учебное заведение</a> </h1>
<br><br>
<h1><a class="test">Специальное учебное заведение2</a> </h1>
```

Comment: В первом примере буква `y` у меня всё равно рвёт подчёркивание

Comment: @andreymal странно. может браузер старый не поддерживающий фичу?

Comment: Поддерживает, подчёркивание сдвинуто вниз ниже чем без этого стиля. Но сдвинуто недостаточно, из-за чего буква всё равно пересекает подчёркивание - скорее всего это шрифт дерьмо со слишком длинными буквами)